# contact info not sending to phpmyadmin

Tags: html, database, connection

I am facing issues connecting to database or creating database connection. My localhost is not sending any data to the database, it doesn't show any errors either. Could you help me? All of the files were originally downloaded, I changed a few stuff, didn't work originally.

My database name is amazon and the table name is `contact_form_info`. Below is my connection and html file.

**get_response.php**

```
   <?php //temp

require 'config.php';

$conn = Connect();
$contactname = $_POST['name'];
$contactEmail = $_POST['Email'];
$contactMessage = $_POST['Message'];

$query = "INSERT INTO contact_form_info ('nome', 'email', 'message') VALUES ('$contactname', '$contactEmail', '$contactMessage')";

// $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

// $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['contactname'], $_POST['contactEmail'], $_POST['contactMessage']);

/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
  echo "Obrigado por nos contactar. <br>";
  printf("rows inserted: %d\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
} else {
  echo "Erro ao inserir dados";
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

$conn->close();
?>
```

**config.php**

```
function Connect()
{
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbName = "amazon";
// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbName) or die($conn->connect_error);
return $conn;
}
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

**html form**

```
            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">

            <fieldset>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="six columns mob-whole">
                    <label for="contactname">Nome <span class="required">*</span></label>                                  
                        <input name="contactname" type="text" id="contactname" placeholder="Nome" value="" />                           
                  </div>

                  <div class="six columns mob-whole">   
                    <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>                                
                        <input name="contactEmail" type="text" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Exemplo@host.com" value="" />                         
                </div>                          

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="twelve columns">
                     <label  for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <textarea name="contactMessage"  id="contactMessage" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div>
                 <button class="submit full-width">Enviar</button>
                 <div id="image-loader">
                    <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" />
                 </div>
              </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Comment: config.php * <?php  //temp
function Connect()
{
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbName = "amazon";
// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbName) or die($conn->connect_error);
return $conn;
}
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>

Comment: hi are you sure your usename is username. Its root by default assuming you didnt changed it

Comment: hey, ye, you're right, thanks. but still stays on loading

Comment: is the connection stablished?

Comment: in  $_POST['name'] the variable you are checking is `name`. However you are  sending `contactname` from your html. Same mistake in other fields as well.

Comment: thanks Ramesh, its fixed now. how do i test the connection? i tried on the easyphp codetester and didnt work. sorry im hella noob

Comment: noticed this error on console and I don't know what it means: jquery.min.js:6 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www/trabpsi_amazonia/inc/sendEmail.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.